# Changing taskbar button color on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, delphi, winapi

Multiple instances of the same application are running at the same time, and since each has multiple windows, it is not easy for the user to navigate between them. I help users by setting the **titlebar color** of different application instances to a different value. For example, all windows of the app instance started first will have red titlebar, all windows of the second instance will have a green one, etc.

It would also be useful to set the **taskbar button color** of app instances to the color I use for the titlebar. Is this possible? If not then I would be happy with a solution having similar differentiating effect, like setting the color of the text on the taskbar button, adding an overlay icon to it, etc.

The solution should work on Windows XP and later Windows versions. The language can be C/C++, C# or Delphi. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is hardly possible, with two exceptions: (1) you can draw/manage your own title bar instead of using the default one, but it is very seldom worth it, IMHO. (2) In Windows 7, you can use overlay icons in the taskbar buttons easily.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I could change the color of the titlebar, what I need is changing the taskbar button color. I've found ITaskbarList3, but it requires Windows 7 at least, and I'd like to make the solution work on Windows XP.

Comment: @kol, Andreas surely meant draw/manage your own task bar...

Comment: @TLama Is it really possible? I mean, replacing explorer.exe by a similar app I write?

Comment: @kol: Yeah, but you don't need to go as far as to replacing explorer.exe. You can simply create your own taskbar-like program, and hide the standard one.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand OK, thank you. I wouldn't do that :) If changing the taskbar button color is really impossible, then I will try and add a thin, colored frame to the app icon at runtime.

Comment: The only built in way to change colours of taskbar buttons is the taskbar progress indicator feature introduced in Windows 7. I would not recommend using that since your users will think you are showing them progress. Your idea of using colour in these places goes utterly against the UI standards of the platform. The fact that you feel the need for this suggests that something is wrong with your UI design.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The original design is not mine, and I'm not allowed to change it. The problem is that taskbar buttons belonging to different instances of the same app differ only in their caption, and in my case, the caption is too long, and its visible part does not differ. Moreover, I'm not allowed to change it since another app uses FindWindow to manage these apps. Either you have to move the cursor above taskbar buttons to make the tooltip visible and read the caption from it, or you click on them one after the other to find the instance you need. That's why I started to play with color.

Comment: @kol but u still can add your own palette "all MyApp instances" and there give the, different colors or whatever. That just would be optional add-on, not the substitute of OS UI. For example you may make floating palette windows. Or plugin to some shell extender like TrueLaunchBar - not replacing Windows stock one, but adding secondary one especially for your app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot hope to achieve differently coloured taskbar buttons.

You could install your own shell and take complete control of the taskbar, but you can't expect your clients to do that.

You cannot expect to paint over the top of the Windows taskbar. The taskbar is animated. How are you going to keep up with that? How are you going to even know where the buttons are? I don't believe that there is a public API that will tell you that. I think you have to rule that idea out.

There is an API that allows you to change the colour of a taskbar button. It's the taskbar progress API added in Windows 7. You could use that to make your taskbar buttons yellow, green or red. I personally would not recommend that since the user will think you are showing progress.

The main options that are available to you are to change the window caption, and so the text that appears in the taskbar button. Or to change the icon.